# how to serialize a struct in c?

Tags: c, networking

I have a struct object that comprises of several primitive data types, pointers and struct pointers. I want to send it over a socket so that it can be used at the other end. As I want to pay the serialization cost upfront, how do I initialize an object of that struct so that it can be sent immediately without marshalling? For example

```
struct A {
    int i;  
    struct B *p;
};

struct B {
    long l;
    char *s[0];
};

struct A *obj; 

// can do I initialize obj?
int len = sizeof(struct A) + sizeof(struct B) + sizeof(?);
obj = (struct A *) malloc(len);
...

write(socket, obj, len);

// on the receiver end, I want to do this
char buf[len];

read(socket, buf, len);
struct A *obj = (struct A *)buf;
int i = obj->i;
char *s = obj->p->s[0];
int i obj.i=1; obj.p.
```

Thank you.

Comment: One note: Why is `struct A` having a pointer to `struct B`, but allocated as if the `struct B` is placed right after `struct A`? You should have at least set `obj->p = (void *)((char *)obj + sizeof(struct A))` if you really wanted to allocate them like that. This is besides the general wrongness in your solution.

Comment: You're going to run into a problem that you will need to resolve when carrying pointers inside your struct. Since a pointer is just a memory address, that memory address has no meaning on another machine. This means that you will need to serialize whatever information that pointer points to (and it can become troublesome if you have many levels of pointers to objects within structs). You might want to consider having your structs fulfill a contract that ensures pointers are dereferenced before serialized.

Comment: I *strongly* advise against trying to pack a structure across a socket. Rather, you should be rolling a protocol buffer that holds the data in a defined, concrete, and platform *independent* format, Send that, and have the other end unpack it and reconstruct the package. It will be considerably less troublesome in the long-term, especially if you design the package with foresight for expansion by accounting for potentially variable-content.

Comment: Two things. Why not just send it as bytes? Unless both sides have different CPUs, it shouldn't be a problem. And another thing about pointers is that even if the pointers can be consumed on the receiving side and somehow be used there, sending pointers is an invitation for an attack.

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze, _Unless both sides have different CPUs..._ even though this by itself is a source of problem, since there are way too many CPU types and variations out there, even on same CPUs just sending them as bytes and receiving them is not correct. Think of one end having optimization on and one not. Then easily one would choose different padding for the structure and break the layout.

Comment: @Shahbaz Just tightly pack the structure (via `#pragma pack`) and ensure at compile time that its size is correct. And then, if there are any alignment issues, work around them in code or use your own, known padding instead of the compiler's and still pack the structure tightly.

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze, you need to be sure you use the exact same architecture, exact same compiler, exact same options, exact same everything. Why not just solve the problem properly?

Comment: @Shahbaz Exact same everything isn't necessary. Compilers and options can differ. CPU-wise you're only interested in: sizes of types, endianness and how the CPU handles unaligned memory accesses. In many cases type sizes aren't a problem and all 8-,16-,32- and 64-bit types are available.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This answer is besides the problems with your `malloc`.

Unfortunately, you cannot find a nice *trick* that would still be compatible with the standard. The *only* way of properly serializing a structure is to separately dissect each element into bytes, write them to an unsigned char array, send them over the network and put the pieces back together on the other end. In short, you would need a lot of shifting and bitwise operations.

In certain cases you would need to define a kind of protocol. In your case for example, you need to be sure you always put the object `p` is pointing to right after `struct A`, so once recovered, you can set the pointer properly. Did everyone say enough already that you can't send pointers through network?

Another protocolish thing you may want to do is to write the size allocated for the flexible array member `s` in `struct B`. Whatever layout for your serialized data you choose, obviously both sides should respect.

It is important to note that you cannot rely on anything machine specific such as order of bytes, structure paddings or size of basic types. This means that you should serialize each field of the element separately and assign them fixed number of bytes.

Answer (score 5):

The simplest way to do this may be to allocate a chunk of memory to hold everything. For instance, consider a struct as follows:

```
typedef struct A {
  int v;
  char* str;
} our_struct_t;
```

Now, the *simplest* way to do this is to create a defined format and pack it into an array of bytes. I will try to show an example:

```
int sLen = 0;
int tLen = 0;
char* serialized = 0;
char* metadata = 0;
char* xval = 0;
char* xstr = 0;
our_struct_t x;
x.v   = 10;
x.str = "Our String";
sLen  = strlen(x.str); // Assuming null-terminated (which ours is)
tLen  = sizeof(int) + sLen; // Our struct has an int and a string - we want the whole string not a mem addr
serialized = malloc(sizeof(char) * (tLen + sizeof(int)); // We have an additional sizeof(int) for metadata - this will hold our string length
metadata = serialized;
xval = serialized + sizeof(int);
xstr = xval + sizeof(int);
*((int*)metadata) = sLen; // Pack our metadata
*((int*)xval) = x.v; // Our "v" value (1 int)
strncpy(xstr, x.str, sLen); // A full copy of our string
```

So this example copies the data into an array of size `2 * sizeof(int) + sLen` which allows us a single integer of metadata (i.e. string length) and the extracted values from the struct. To deserialize, you could imagine something as follows:

```
char* serialized = // Assume we have this
char* metadata = serialized;
char* yval = metadata + sizeof(int);
char* ystr = yval + sizeof(int);
our_struct_t y;
int sLen = *((int*)metadata);
y.v = *((int*)yval);
y.str = malloc((sLen + 1) * sizeof(char)); // +1 to null-terminate
strncpy(y.str, ystr, sLen);
y.str[sLen] = '\0';
```

As you can see, our array of bytes is well-defined. Below I have detailed the structure:

- Bytes 0-3 : Meta-data (string length)
- Bytes 4-7 : X.v (value)
- Bytes 8 - sLen : X.str (value)

This kind of well-defined structure allows you to recreate the struct on any environment if you follow the defined convention. To send this structure over the socket, now, depends on how you develop your protocol. You can first send an integer packet containing the total length of the packet which you just constructed, or you can expect that the metadata is sent first/separately (logically separately, this technically can still all be sent at the same time) and then you know how much data to receive on the client-side. For instance, if I receive metadata value of `10` then I can expect `sizeof(int) + 10` bytes to follow to complete the struct. In general, this is probably `14` bytes.

**EDIT**

I will list some clarifications as requested in the comments.

I do a full copy of the string so it is in (logically) contiguous memory. That is, all the data in my serialized packet is actually full data - there are no pointers. This way, we can send a single buffer (we call is `serialized`) over the socket. If simply send the pointer, the user receiving the pointer would expect that pointer to be a valid memory address. However, it is unlikely that your memory addresses will be exactly the same. Even if they are, however, he will not have the same data at that address as you do (except in very limited and specialized circumstances).

Hopefully this point is made more clear by looking at the deserialization process (this is on the receiver's side). Notice how I allocate a struct to hold the information sent by the sender. If the sender did not send me the full string but instead only the memory address, I could not actually reconstruct the data which was sent (even on the same machine we have two distinct virtual memory spaces which are not the same). So in essence, a pointer is only a good mapping for the originator.

Finally, as far as "structs within structs" go, you will need to have several functions for each struct. That said, it is possible that you can reuse the functions. For instance, if I have two structs `A` and `B` where `A` contains `B`, I can have two serialize methods:

```
char* serializeB()
{
  // ... Do serialization
}

char* serializeA()
{
  char* B = serializeB();
  // ... Either add on to serialized version of B or do some other modifications to combine the structures
}
```

So you should be able to get away with a single serialization method for each struct.

Comment: Thanks, this is great. A more commented code would be great if you could, because I am not understanding some steps. why do you full copy the string? In case I have a structure inside another structure, I have to make multiple serialise functions for each different struct right? Thanks Best Regards

Comment: in case that you have more than a char* inside the struct you need to have 2 metadata to refer to the size of both char* ? thanks

Comment: @moursika: The metadata is defined to allow variable length strings. If you create a fixed-length packet, you can most-likely eliminate metadata entirely. But yes, if you want an arbitrary number of arbitrary length strings, you will need some scheme to do so (likely in metadata or something similar) otherwise you will be unable to deserialize your data.

Answer (score 1):

You should serialize the data in a platform independent way.

Here is an example using the [Binn](https://github.com/liteserver/binn) library (my creation):

```
  binn *obj;

  // create a new object
  obj = binn_object();

  // add values to it
  binn_object_set_int32(obj, "id", 123);
  binn_object_set_str(obj, "name", "Samsung Galaxy Charger");
  binn_object_set_double(obj, "price", 12.50);
  binn_object_set_blob(obj, "picture", picptr, piclen);

  // send over the network
  send(sock, binn_ptr(obj), binn_size(obj));

  // release the buffer
  binn_free(obj);
```

If you don't want to use strings as keys you can use a binn_map which uses  integers as keys. There is also support for lists. And you can insert a structure inside another (nested structures). eg:

```
  binn *list;

  // create a new list
  list = binn_list();

  // add values to it
  binn_list_add_int32(list, 123);
  binn_list_add_double(list, 2.50);

  // add the list to the object
  binn_object_set_list(obj, "items", list);

  // or add the object to the list
  binn_list_add_object(list, obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

Interpret your data and understand what you want to serialize. You want to serialize an integer and a structure of type B (recursivelly, you want to serialize an int, a long, and an array of strings). Then serialize them. The length you need it sizeof(int) + sizeof(long) + ∑strlen(s[i])+1.

On the other hand, serialization is a solved problem (multiple times actually). Are you sure you need to hand write a serialization routine ? Why don't you use D-Bus or a simple RPC call ? Please consider using them.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the method provided by @RageD but it didn't work.

The `int` value I got from deserialization was not the original one.

For me, `memcpy()` works for non-string variables. (You can still use `strcpy()` for `char *`)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct A {
    int a;
    char *str;
} test_struct_t;

char *serialize(test_struct_t t) {
    int str_len = strlen(t.str);

    int size = 2 * sizeof(int) + str_len;
    char *buf = malloc(sizeof(char) * (size+1));

    memcpy(buf, &t.a, sizeof(int));
    memcpy(buf + sizeof(int), &str_len, sizeof(int));
    memcpy(buf + sizeof(int) * 2, t.str, str_len);
    buf[size] = '\0';

    return buf;
}

test_struct_t deserialize(char *buf) {
    test_struct_t t;

    memcpy(&t.a, buf, sizeof(int));

    int str_len;
    memcpy(&str_len, buf+sizeof(int), sizeof(int));

    t.str = malloc(sizeof(char) * (str_len+1));
    memcpy(t.str, buf+2*sizeof(int), str_len);
    t.str[str_len] = '\0';

    return t;
}

int main() {
    char str[15] = "Hello, world!";

    test_struct_t t;
    t.a = 123;
    t.str = malloc(strlen(str) + 1);
    strcpy(t.str, str);
    printf("original values: %d %s\n", t.a, t.str);

    char *buf = serialize(t);
    test_struct_t new_t = deserialize(buf);
    printf("new values: %d %s\n", new_t.a, new_t.str);

    return 0;
}
```

And the output of the code above is:

```
original values: 123 Hello, world!
new values: 123 Hello, world!
```

Answer (score -1):

@Shahbaz is right I would think you actually want this

```
int len = sizeof(struct A);
obj = (struct A *) malloc(len);
```

But also you will run into problems when sending a pointer to another machine as the address the pointer points to means nothing on the other machine.

Comment: Except that cast is harmful... don't do it.

Comment: That will not work. Since there are pointers in the struct, the serialized version would have a pointer to a (probably) bad memory address.

Comment: @H2CO3 why is that cast harmful? for my own benefit.

Comment: @spartacus [It's nicely explained here.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc/605858#605858)

Comment: @spartacus Then why not just `obj = (struct A*) malloc(sizeof(struct A))` ?